# C# Radio Buttons - Remove Auto-grouping (VS 2008 Designer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, radio-button, radio-group

I'm using VS 2008 and C#. I've created three radio buttons (using the VS designer) on the same form and they are being automatically grouped. I'd like the user to be able to select all of the radio buttons (not just one of the three).

How do I ungroup them? I can't find a property in the radio button(s) that handles this and am at a loss. Modifying the auto-generated designer code (which I'm sure where the grouping is being done) is not recommended and can lead to a lot of issues in Visual Studio, so I'm guessing the best solutions would be either a property that I for some reason cannot find, or a way to programmatically ungroup them when the form is initialized.

Thanks!

Comment: I've known from the beginning that they are being automatically grouped because they are in the same container, so putting them in different invisible containers would definitely work, but I really thought there should be a better solution for this... that approach seemed sloppy.

Answer (score 4):

You should use checkboxes in this case.

If you really are stuck on radiobuttons then place each button in its own panel.

Here's the [Microsoft explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc%28VS.80%29.aspx) to back up the grouping concept.

Comment: My client is obsessed with radio buttons for some reason and requested them for this piece specifically.

Comment: well thats great.. but what happens when a user accidently chooses one.  there's no way to clear it out now.  That's why a checkbox is more appropriate.  Just something to point out to the client.

Comment: Eh, good point. I guess I'll use separate containers for now and request he change them to checkboxes. Thanks boo! ;)

Comment: Radio/option buttons are *not* designed for this. It's your job to explain to the client why; that's why they hired you. You and they both need a check box. This is not unusual: every other application on your client's machine works in the exact same way. Most people don't know the difference, even if they ask for them by name. If you struggle to explain it, borrow the analogy that motivated the name: you can't have multiple stations selected and playing at a time on a radio.

Answer (score 0):

put them on seperate containers.

Comment: I don't want to add a separate container just so they won't be grouped, especially since they are right next to each other. There has to be a better solution, or at least I'd hope so.

Answer (score 0):

I REALLY shouldn't use radiobuttons because if they act separately, then you won't be able to unselect them. What you could use is use chackboxes *styled as* radiobuttons... I believe it's possible to do, but I don't know how (I may be wrong though)